# Can you ask questions anonymously?

Tags: support, feature-request

On SE sites is there an option to post questions anonymously so they don't show your name or show up on your user data?
(I have put "support" and "feature request" as tags because i dont know whether the feature does exist.)

Comment: Can you share the reason behind your question?  That may help people write more helpful answers.

Comment: You are already kind of anonymous... I have no proof that you are Joe Smith, living at 315 Main St, Sometown, WI. As far as I know you are actually Joe Smiths poodle. If you are worried about asking an "embarrassing" question I would say maybe either don't worry about it, or if you think it's really bad just generalize the question in chat and say "Are questions about poodle/human hybrids acceptable?"

Comment: From my experience on Quora, the questions by Anonymous are usually worthless and I wish I could just block Anonymous. Questions like "Which is best processor?" with no other details, asked by Anonymous. For what reason was that anonymous? Probably because people can hardly answer such a dumb question without chastising the asker.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes, you can.

#### Method 1: Ask anonymously from the start

The [simplest method](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89248/274942) is, essentially:

1. Log out of all sites.
2. Navigate to the site you want. [Ask your question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).
3. You'll get a temporary account based on browser cookies. If you log out, you'll lose access.

There are, of course, downsides:

- When you log out, you won't be able to edit the question or comment on it as the original asker.
- You'll get no rep from asking the question (if that's at all a motivation).

#### Method 2: Request dissociation

You can ask a question using your actual account and then [request for it to be dissociated from your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/274942). It will be anonymized, and folks won't be able to see who asked it. That said, as that Meta post points out, the other sites might archive the post, so you risk not having complete anonymity outside Stack Exchange.

Also, don't abuse this . . . and don't use it unless you really need to.

#### Method 3: Use a secondary account

This is one of those few [valid uses for sockpuppets](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/274942). You create a full second account and ask the question via that. You retain the privileges needed to edit the question and comment as the asker, and you'll get rep for it.

That said, **I would not recommend this**. You need to be careful that this account and your first one don't interact in any way with each other. That means:

- Your normal account shouldn't vote on the question. I would also advise not using it to vote on any of the answers, edit them, approve edits, comment, flag . . . or really do anything on the thread.
- Your secondary account should avoid the same things with respect to your main account. Actually, once you're done with the question, I'd advise not using this account. Maybe even delete it, at that point.

I did this once so I could test out some low-rep user and limitations, and to see posts as such a user would. I asked a question and ended up getting enough rep to bypass the restrictions I was trying to test. Darn. So I haven't touched it in . . . seven months, I think. I won't use it again.

Again, I don't recommend this. And it might look suspicious to us mods; if we see user IPs match, we'll do some digging to see what's up. It looks even worse if you make *multiple* accounts.

Answer (score 2):

#### No, you can't post a question anonymously from your normal account while still being able to see it yourself on your profile

There is no such option. If you want to be "anonymous" you would need to create another account with which you ask these questions or log out of your normal account so that there is no connection to your normal account. But this would mean that you couldn't see the question from your normal account. You would need to keep track of each account separately to keep track of your questions.

The only feature that comes a little bit close to this is the option to hide certain sites of the network from your general profile. Click on your profile, then "Edit Profile & Settings", under "Site Settings" click "Hide Communities". To cite from those settings (no emphasis added):

> Hiding a community means other users will not see it in your Communities list or Top Network Posts. **It does not, however, mean your activity is private.**
>
> New sites that you join will be linked to your other communities by default.

---

Just to make this clear: if you feel the need to post anonymously you should ask yourself why you are doing this. If it's because you for example don't want people who know your username in real life to know that you are asking about them on sites like InterpersonalSkills.SE that might be fine. But if you feel that you should create a new account to ask questions on a site where you are already active those questions might not be a good fit for the site and if people realize that you are trying to create additional accounts to post crappy questions your normal account might very well be banned.

StackExchange is not made for partial anonymity.

Comment: This isn't quite true; you can indeed ask anonymously if you log out properly. And it's always been [a core principle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79391/274942).

Comment: @HDE226868 Maybe I misinterpreted the question. I read this as "I want to ask a question from my normal account and be able to see it on my profile - but it shouldn't show my name to others" as the OP asked about posting questions "anonymously so they don't show your name or show up on your user data". I edited to make it a bit more clear what I am trying to say.